# Change grunt-serve default path

Tags: gruntjs

I run `grunt serve` from command line and I can access the server through localhost:9000.

How can I configure grunt-serve to load a default file when it starts ?

Answer (score 0):

But, you can change address and the port of server in the file ''Gruntfile.js''.

just here

```html
 // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 80,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
```